# Get filepath from a routed page

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I have a masterpage and I'm trying to get the current filename. So for instance I am on http://website.com/test.aspx I would like to use the Request object to get "test.aspx"

I'm not a new comer to .net and have been able to do this before but the problem is that i'm using routing.

In my Global.asax I have this

routes.MapPageRoute("test", "newroutedurl/", "~/test.aspx");

So I can go to http://website.com/newroutedurl/ and it routes to text.aspx - All that is fine but I cannot seem to find a way to get the actual file path. I would like to return "test.aspx" but it is returning "newroutedurl/"

Is there a way I can get around this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the **`actual file path`** or do you want **`test.aspx`**? What was the request that got you to the page? **`http://website.com/test.aspx`** or **`http://website.com/newroutedurl/`**?

Comment: I would like the filename for example "test.aspx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this in your code behind, it should return text.aspx:

```
var pageName = Page.GetType().Name.Replace("_", ".");
```

Comment: It does work if run in Test.aspx.cs but I need this to work in a Masterpage CS file